# IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced save/restore state operators

Tags: java, html, css, itext

I am working on `iText` converting HTML with CSS to PDF.

In my CSS, I have:

```
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #e6e6e6 100%);
```

With this, it is throwing below exception:

```
IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced save/restore state operators
(exception at document.close();)
```

Here's the code I have written:

```
Document document = null;
try{
 FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\DEV\\testpdf.html"); 
 fileOuputStream.write(str.getBytes());
 String CSS = "D:\\DEV\\all.css";
 CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();

 CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new FileInputStream(CSS));
 cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);
 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\DEV\\testpdf.html");
    // step 1
   document = new Document();
    // step 2
   PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("pdf.pdf"));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
    CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
    htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
    PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
    HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
    CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);
    // XML Worker
    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
    p.parse(fileInputStream);
    // step 4
  //  XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, fileInputStream);
    //step 5

     fileInputStream.close();
     fileOuputStream.close();
    System.out.println( "PDF Created!" );


}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
 document.close();
```

If I remove this from my CSS:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #e6e6e6 100%);
```

Then, I am able to generate PDF with out above exception.

iText version:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Which version of iText are you using?

Comment: itextpdf - 5.4.2
xmlworker  - 5.4.1

Comment: Can you try with the most recent version. Also make sure that the version number of XML Worker and iText always correspond.

Comment: itextpdf - 5.5.2 xmlworker - 5.5.2
No exceptions,
when i change jar versions and commenting CSS linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #e6e6e6 100%);
when i use/uncomment above CSS code, still same issue :
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced save/restore state operators.

Comment: OK, it sounds like a bug. Unbalanced save/restore state operators means that there's a `saveState()` call without a `restoreState()` call (or vice-versa). Now that we've established that the problem occurs in a recent iText / XML Worker version, I'll put this on the official TODO list. If you are a customer, the ticket will get priority treatment. If not, you'll have to wait until the next release.